# Solving RSA cipher without calculator

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, cryptography

I have a question: Encrypt the message UPLOAD using RSA with $n=3\cdot 31$ and $e =17$.

My question is, how can I solve this with a calculator and in an efficient manner due to being in an exam environment?

For example, for $U$ I got $C= 21^{17}\pmod{93}$. Is there any shortcut I can use?

Comment: Compute the squares and use $17=2^4+1$.

Comment: Some methods are listed at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation